# Remove parent Item on clicking child item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a element while clicking on one of its child nodes using pure JavaScript or jQuery library.

There are more than one `<div>` with the same class. I have followed answers on StackOverflow but none satisfied my coding. None is working.

below is my code

```js
function removetask(e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="div-main">
  <h1>task 1</h1>
  <a href="#" onclick="removetask(this)">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
  <h1>task 2</h1>
  <a href="#" onclick="removetask(this)">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
  <h1>task 3</h1>
  <a href="#" onclick="removetask(this)">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `div-main` is the immediate parent.  You have too many references to parentNode it seems.  It should work if you remove one of them from each chain, if i'm reading this right.

Comment: Modern browsers will let you just do `e.parentNode.remove()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go the jQuery route it would be.

```
$(e).closest('.div-main').remove();
//or
$(e).parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function removetask1 (e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}

function removetask2 (e) {
  $(e).closest('.div-main').remove();
}

function removetask3 (e) {
  $(e).parent().remove();
}
</script>
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 1</h1>
    <a href="#"  onclick="removetask1(this)">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 2</h1>
    <a href="#"  onclick="removetask2(this)">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 3</h1>
    <a href="#"  onclick="removetask3(this)">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not works. I tried this...But why it is not working i don't know

Comment: Afaik, inline bindings require their functions to be declared before them, not after, otherwise they will be undefined.  I've updated the solution to show a working example of all three ways.

Comment: @Igor Does not Work :p

Comment: @AlexGarretjones, if above code doesn't work, then something wrong in your code only

Comment: @AlexGarretjones, You should tell more details to us, above demo in the answer is not working when hit `Run code snippet`? or you migrated above solution to your project but not working? if not working in your project, what is the error in the web console?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code. Please try.

jQuery

---

```
$(".div-main a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".div-main").remove();
});
```

Html

---

```
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 1</h1>
    <a href="#"  >Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 2</h1>
    <a href="#" >Close</a>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
    <h1>task 3</h1>
    <a href="#" >Close</a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link

---

https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/st8d6y03/1/